# Dystopian collective farm that grows corn, possibly on space station. Workers must confess to & report all petty crimes

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel

[Another one I posted on Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/topic/show/21346048-teen-ya-scifi-dark-dystopian-collective-farm-that-grows-corn-possibl), but haven't got anywhere with.

Age group: children / teens

Date: 1970s / 80s (read it late 80s / early 90s).

Nation of origin: unknown (but probably not Australian).

Plot details (so far as I can remember):
The book starts with the protagonist forced to work on a collective farm growing corn. During the day, the protagonist sees a co-worker steal a corn cob and eat it. In the showers after work, all workers have to denounce all petty crimes (their own, and others') to a Big Brother-like voice coming from a box over the shower; failure to do so results in the dinner being cancelled for the entire workforce. The protagonist decides not to betray his co worker. When they go to their meal, they find they will not be fed as the co-worker confessed his crime, but the protagonist failed to denounce him.

I am not sure, but I have the idea that this collective from hell may have been on a space station.

I also have the idea (more sure on this) that this book may have been a sequel. The earlier book finished on a positive note, and I recall finding the crash into dystopia somewhat shocking.

Comment: Was the protagonist definitely male? I have a memory of something similar but the protagonist was female - confessing in the shower to another person making her feel uncomfortable, then that person disappears. I'll see if I can dig up what that's from.

Comment: I'm pretty sure (almost certain) that the protagonist was male.  Also, the 'person' he confessed to did not disappear - it was a box on the wall.  But I'd still be interested in what you find.  Cheers.